# Go bitwise operation performance mystery

Tags: performance, go

While benchmarking the performance of conversion from byte arrays to `uint32`s, I noticed that the conversion ran faster when starting with the least significant bits:

```
package blah

import (
    "testing"
    "encoding/binary"
    "bytes"
)

func BenchmarkByteConversion(t *testing.B) {
    var i uint32 = 3419234848
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, i)
    b := buf.Bytes()

    for n := 0; n < t.N; n++ {
        // Start with least significant bit: 0.27 nanos
        value := uint32(b[3]) | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[2])<<16 | uint32(b[0])<<24

        // Start with most significant bit: 0.68 nanos
        // value := uint32(b[0])<<24 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[3])
        _ = value
    }
}
```

When I run `go test -bench=.`, I get 0.27 nanos per iteration when computing `value` the first way, and 0.68 nanos per iteration when computing `value` the second way. Why is it twice as fast to start with the least significant bits when `|`ing together numbers?

Comment: On a 3GHz machine, one clock cycle is about 0.3ns. Your benchmark results are likely inaccurate and, like all microbenchmarks like this, highly influenced by factors outside the code being measured (eg the setup and loop iteration).

Comment: Hmm, but isn’t the idea of the benchmark that it’ll do millions of operations so that there won’t be much noise in the average measurement? Every time I run the bench it’s at least twice as slow for method 2

Comment: Because the compiler generates different machine code. Nothing more to say here. Might change in the next compiler version and be different in the one after that again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no mystery. Optimization!

```
package blah

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkByteConversionLeast(t *testing.B) {
    var i uint32 = 3419234848
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, i)
    b := buf.Bytes()

    for n := 0; n < t.N; n++ {
        // Start with least significant bit: 0.27 nanos
        value := uint32(b[3]) | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[2])<<16 | uint32(b[0])<<24
        _ = value
    }
}

func BenchmarkByteConversionMost(t *testing.B) {
    var i uint32 = 3419234848
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, i)
    b := buf.Bytes()

    for n := 0; n < t.N; n++ {
        // Start with most significant bit: 0.68 nanos
        value := uint32(b[0])<<24 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[3])
        _ = value
    }
}
```

Output:

```
go test silly_test.go -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkByteConversionLeast-4      2000000000           0.72 ns/op
BenchmarkByteConversionMost-4       2000000000           1.80 ns/op
```

It should be obvious. Bounds check elimination.

---

Just use common sense. If you check the array bounds for indices 3, 2, 1, and 0 you can stop checking at 3 since, obviously, 2, 1, and 0 will also be valid. If you check the array bounds for indices 0, 1, 2, and 3 you have to check the bounds for them all. One bounds check versus four bounds checks.

[Wikipedia: Bounds checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking)

[Wikipedia: Bounds-checking elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds-checking_elimination)

---

You should also be reading good code, like the Go standard library. For example,

```
func (littleEndian) PutUint64(b []byte, v uint64) {
    _ = b[7] // early bounds check to guarantee safety of writes below
    b[0] = byte(v)
    b[1] = byte(v >> 8)
    b[2] = byte(v >> 16)
    b[3] = byte(v >> 24)
    b[4] = byte(v >> 32)
    b[5] = byte(v >> 40)
    b[6] = byte(v >> 48)
    b[7] = byte(v >> 56)
}
```

Comment: "It should be obvious" is not a very helpful explanation.

Comment: It’s not obvious to me what is going on. What bounds check is being eliminated and why?

Comment: I guess he means that if you first do an access on the higher indice, the compiler will skip bound check on next access on lower indice.  Its probably an optimisation the compiler can easily do. TIL